Running out of space when tyring to install Nvidia gpu driver although there is plenty of disk space availible
I'm currently trying to install an Nvidia gpu driver but receiving the following error:
king@kingss:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Correcting dependencies... Done 
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libamd-comgr2 libhsa-runtime64-1 libibmad5  libucx0                 nsight-compute-target
  libamdhip64-5 libhsakmt1         libibumad3 linux-image-6.6.9-amd64 nsight-systems-target
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

Installing dependencies:                                                                                           
  nvidia-cuda-dev                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                   
Summary:                                                                                                           
  Upgrading: 0, Installing: 1, Removing: 0, Not Upgrading: 282                                                     
  111 not fully installed or removed.                                                                              
  Download size: 0 B / 705 MB                                                                                      
  Space needed: 2410 MB / 0 B available                                                                            
                                                                                                                   
Warning: More space needed than available: 2410 MB > 0 B, installation may fail                                    
Continue anyway? [y/N] 

I have tried to check and understand the filesystem using df which obtained the following:
king@kingss:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            16279672        0  16279672   0% /dev
tmpfs            3264492     1868   3262624   1% /run
/dev/nvme1n1p2  23854928 23790520         0 100% /
tmpfs           16322448        0  16322448   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
efivarfs             248      224        20  93% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme1n1p5   1883580       96   1769464   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme1n1p3   9510080  3412800   5592604  38% /var
/dev/nvme1n1p6 454066608  3391032 427536760   1% /home
/dev/nvme1n1p1 500045120      768 500044352   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            3264488     2552   3261936   1% /run/user/1000

The only partition that appears to be at 100% capacity is /dev/nvme1n1p2.
Would resizing this partition enable the installation?
If yes, how would this be done?
Thankyou

Most software is installed there, so yes.    But this will require a live boot disk.  I'd recommend shrinking /boot/efi to 1-2 G and then resizing nvme1n1p2 into that space.

A backup of most important files in that partition is recommended, another choice may be to clean up that partition, delete unnecessary files (be careful) and moving your swap to another partition.

Does this answer your question? How to resize partitions?

/dev/nvme1n1p2  23854928 23790520         0 100% /
This is the line that gives details of your root. It is 100% full.  You have spare space on /home and /var, but not your /.
You can adjust your partitions adjust the sizes, or just move some files/delete some files.
